# JBPM: What do the numbers after `g=` in JBPM jpdl.xml mean?

Tags: java, jbpm, jpdl

```
<process name="decisionsUsingTransitions" xmlns="http://jbpm.org/4.0/jpdl">
   <start g="72,168,48,48" name="Start">
      <transition to="Decision"/>
   </start>
   <decision expr="#{opcao}" g="192,168,48,48" name="Decision">
      <transition g="217,84:23,-21" name="Opção A" to="Opção A"/>
      <transition g="-26,-20" name="Opção B" to="Opção B"/>
      <transition g="217,302:22,5" name="Opção C" to="Opção C"/>
   </decision>
```

the above is part of a JBPM jpdl.xml file, I'm wondering what do the numbers (i.e, 72,168,48,48) after `g=` mean?

Answer (score 0):

The numbers after 'g=' are simply coordinates (used by whichever graphic editor you've employed in creating your JBPM flow) to 'draw' the graphical representation of your flow. They do nothing to affect the normal transition between states and can be omitted alltogether, should you not use such a graphical tool.